# Place a Page before Context Blocks

Tags: blocks

I want to achieve this result in my Drupal front page:

```
[Headers]
[Welcome Block]
[View of contents]
```

So I created a Welcome Page (as a Basic Page), and put it as a *Front Page* from *site configuration*.
Then I add the view by the context module.

The problem is that the welcome page appears after the view, at the bottom of the page:

```
[Headers]
[SECTION Content]
  [View of contents] (view, added with context)
  [Welcome]          (Basic Page with path /welcome)
[/SECTION Content]
```

A possible solution is to make a Block instead of a page, but I would have no more welcome/ path where to link the *front*. I want also to use a page so that editors can edit, update and translate that when needed. With blocks I should add higher permissions. My purpose is just to show the welcome basic page before the view of contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use panel page for this.
Create a panel, set it is as front page and pull the things you want to pull like blocks, views, nodes etc.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen.R, I prefer not to use panels since they add too many degrees of freedom, and stick to Context + Views. Of course this solution is good, and Panels are ultra-widely used. But my purpose (in case that'd be possible) is _just_ to display my basic page on the top of other content added with context.

In this case I want to use a page so that editors can edit that. With blocks I should add higher permissions.